# how to chk if span tag contain text or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrW2n/9/)
if patient has time slot alloted already then make color yellow using jquery(client side).
                            in my fiddle if i allot time slot first time then color is green and at the same time when allot
                            next time slot then previous time slot is grey. i have to make it yellow.
                            for that i have to find span tag in table and check wheather contains text or not 
                            if contains text then make it yellow.But i m new in jquery.i search lot but not getting.
                            how can i do that.

//This is button click code

```
  $("#<%=btnSelect.ClientID%>").click(function ()           {


                var cells = $('#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(3)');


                var i = 0;
                var topcell = false;

                cells.each(function ()
                {
                    var $cell = $(this);

                    if ($cell.hasClass('csstdhighlight'))
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            $cell.find('span').text(jQuery('#<%=txtPatientName.ClientID%>').val());
                            topcell = $cell;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $cell.remove();

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                });
                if (topcell && i > 1) topcell.attr('rowspan', i);
                $("#tableAppointment tr").each(function ()
                {

                    $('td', this).each(function ()
                    {
                        var value = $(this).find("span").val();

                        if (!value)//i m chking like this
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        { //make it yellow                      
                        }
                    })

                })

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: `$('#tableAppointment tbody tr td:nth-child(3)')` returns only one element and using each is redundant.

Comment: console.log is undefined

Comment: no, console.log() is not undefined.

Comment: @undefined if i allot time slot first time then color is green and at the same time when allot next time slot then previous time slot make yellow using jquery any other logic

Comment: @nikhil if you have any problem still then come to this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12535/anonmous

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with less codes? to we become more focused on the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
var value = $(this).find("span").val();
```

write

```
var value = $(this).find("span").text();
```

and if you want to check html inside span then use

```
var value = $(this).find("span").html();
```

UPDATE :-

```
<html><head>
<style>.yell{background:#CCFF00;}.csstd
{
background-color: #ccffcc;
}
table{
background-color: #cccccc;

}</style><script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>var is=false;
$(function(){

$(document).mouseup(function(){is=false;});
$(".csstablelisttd").mousedown(function(e){sen=$(this);
$(".csstd").removeClass("csstd");
  $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstd");
  xco=e.clientX;
  yco=e.clientY;
  is=true;
  return false;
});
document.onmousemove=function(){return false;};
$(".csstablelisttd").mouseenter(function(){
if(is){
  $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstd");
if($(".csstd").length>=6){is=false;}
}
});
$("#update").click(function(){
if($("#names").val())
{
$(".csstd").next().hide();

$(".csstd:first").next().show().attr("rowspan",$(".csstd").length/2).children().html($("#names").val());
$(".csstd").removeClass("csstd").addClass("yell");
}
});
 });</script></head><body>
<table id="tableAppointment" cellspacing="1" width="50%" border="1" align="center">
<thead>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">
</td>
<td >
</td>
<td class="csstablelisttd patientName">
<b>Patient Name</b>
</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td  valign="top" width="70px">
8:00AM
</td>
<td >
0
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
15
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
30
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
45
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td  valign="top" width="90px">
9:00AM
</td>
<td >
0
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
15
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
30
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="csstablelisttd">
<td >
</td>
<td >
45
</td>
<td >
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" id="names" />
<input type="button" id="update" value="update" /> </body></html>
```

Comment: +1 thanks.......but How to iterate through table if span contain text then make that appointment with color yellow.

Comment: r u there somebody is in trouble

Answer (score 6):

```
if($('span').text().length == 0){
  console.log('No Text');
}
else{
  console.log('Has Text');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hj4Bt/1/

Comment: +1 thanks..but How to iterate through table if span contain text then make that appointment with color yellow.

Comment: @Dipak if i allot time slot first time then color is green and at the same time when allot next time slot then previous time slot make yellow

Comment: if span is found then how to find its current row

Comment: $(this).parents('tr'); Should help

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this).find("span").text()` instead. Check if the returned string is empty.

Comment: +1 thanks.......but How to iterate through table if span contain text then make that appointment with color yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FDEep/3/

```
$('input').click(function(){
    // All <span> inside <td>
    $('td span').each(function(index){
        // Check if 'span' is empty
        if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){
            // Change the bg color of the 'span' not empty
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
            // When a span with some value is found, alert the index of the row
            alert( $(this).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex);
        }
    });
});
```

Adapt at your will